# Ascoli's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of differentiable real-valued functions on $[0, 1]$ such that

1. $f_n(0) = c$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$,
2. $|f'_n(x)| \le M$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\forall x \in [0, 1]$

Show that $(f_n)$ has a subsequence which converges uniformly on $[0, 1]$ to a continuous function.

I guess we have to use Ascoli's theorem, but the application for it is super confusing for me. Can someone help out please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uniform boundedness of the derivatives implies by the mean value theorem that for all $x$ and $y$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ $$\left|f_n(x) - f_n(y)\right| \le M |x-y|$$

So, given $ε > 0$, let $δ = ε/2M$ to verify that for $|x-y|<δ$ 
$$\left|f_n(x) - f_n(y)\right| \le M |x-y|\le Mδ<ε$$
which shows that the sequence is equicontinuous. Now, by the first condition you can show that the sequence is also uniformly bounded, since $$\left|f_n(x) - f_n(0)\right| \le M |x-0|\le M\cdot 1 \implies |f_n(x)-c|\le M \implies |f_n(x)|\le M+|c|$$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $n\in \mathbb N$.

So, the sequence is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous and hence you can apply the [Arzela-Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem) to conclude.