# Arzela - Ascoli application

Tags: real-analysis, arzela-ascoli

Let $a>0$ and the sequence $f_n:[-a,a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that the following conditions are true:

$\bullet$ There is $k \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ such that $f_n$   is $(k+1)$-differentiable in $[-a,a]$;

$\bullet$ $f_n^{(i)}(0)=0 \ \forall \ i \in \{0,1,\dots,k\}$

$\bullet$ $|f_n^{k+1}(x)|\leq C.$

Prove that there is a subsequence in $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}}$ that is uniformly convergent in $[-a,a]$.

I know that this must be like this question [Ascoli's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591468/ascolis-theorem/1591471#1591471), but i'm having some hard time one this.

Comment: What have you tried? Arzelà-Ascoli is a theorem about equicontinuous, uniformly bounded families of functions. Have you attempted to show that $\{f_n\}_n$ satisfies these conditions?

Comment: My attempt was something like: Let $x \in [0,a]$, using the mean value theorem we can prove that $f_n^k(x)\leq C\cdot a$ and the same works for $x \in [-a,0].$ I suppose that we can bound $f_n$, but i can't prove this.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. You can try to use that bound to control $f_n^{k-1}$ and so on up to $f$.

Comment: I managed to prove that i will bound $f_n$ by $Ca^k$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And the bound does not depend on $n$. I wrote a hint, continuity follows likewise: note that your proof most likely already shows that $Ca^k$ is actually a Lipschitz constant for all $f_n$.

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** if $f$ is differentiable and $|f'| \leq C$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y|$. Moreover, $|f(x)| = |f(x)-0| \leq C|x-0| \leq Ca$.

Apply this to $f_n^k$ for each $n$. The bound on their derivatives is the same for all of them, so the Lipschitz constant you get is the same for all. The proceed likewise unitl you reach each $f_n$, keeping track of how the bound changes. It will be uniform; this will allow you to conclude that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded and uniformly equicontinuous. Then apply Arzelà-Ascoli.